# How to hide a label in InfoPath when selecting an option on a combo box?

Tags: infopath-rules

When an option is selected from the combo box, I want one label on the form to be hidden. Hiding Labels in InfoPath Designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add a conditional formatting rule to the field that you want to hide.

The condition should be something like "ComboBox | Contains | Value" and then hide this control.

I've created a combo box called field 2 with values *Value1* and *Value2*. I also created a simple text field called field3.

Now I want to hide field 3 when "ComboBox | Contains | Value2". See the result below.

[image]
[image]
[image]