# Hiding Fields in an InfoPath Form

Tags: javascript, infopath, column

Is it possible to hide fields in an InfoPath 2013 field based on the value of another field? Possibly through JavaScript?

I have an InfoPath 2013 form that is linked to a SharePoint 2013 List, and the user wants certain fields to be hidden if the value of another field (a yes/no field) is a certain value. Is this possible? I thought perhaps JavaScript could be used, but I have seen in a couple of places that InfoPath does not have any way of adding JavaScript.

Comment: You can add a Javascript file to your page using the CEWP and codes to hide the fields

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with InfoPath 2013, could you elaborate a little bit on how to do this? Or do you know of a good resource for me too look into? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [Rules](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d) in Infopath.

There is 3 different types of rule that you can use, Validation, Formatting and Action. They are accessible from the top ribbon tab "Home" and are found almost in the right corner.

[image]

Add a **formatting** rule on the field you wanna hide and set the condition to be something like `Yes/No Field is equal to True / False` ( or 1 for True, and 0 for false ) and then set the box "hide this control".

The rules will apply as soon the condition is true. Use the preview to make sure that the rule works as expected.

I've answered a similar question before and added some pictures there. Not pretty but it works.

[How to hide a label in InfoPath when selecting an option on a combo box?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134255/how-to-hide-a-label-in-infopath-when-selecting-an-option-on-a-combo-box/134259#134259)

**Update**

To apply rules to multiple fields you can put those in a **section**. Select a session from the control tab and put your text/controls/buttons/images in there and apply a rule to the whole section.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. Can rules only be applied to fields? Or is there a way to apply a rule to a table row or text?

Comment: Glad you asked! I'm gonna update my answer

Comment: That worked really well. Thanks for all of your help!