# Hiding a section in Infopath Form based on a Value selected in Dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath

I want to hide a section which is having set of text boxes, and by selecting a particular value from a drop down the section has to hide. Can anyone plz help me to achieve this

Comment: I have answered a question similar to this one before. The same applies to a section. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134255/how-to-hide-a-label-in-infopath-when-selecting-an-option-on-a-combo-box/134259#134259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the section which has to be hidden,Insert a table and then inside the table insert all the textboxes and labels.So click on section or table and select **Manage Rules** and use Formatting to hide whole section

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/10/10/how-to-hide-a-group-of-fields-in-a-sharepoint-list-using-infopath-2010-aspx/

Comment: I have added the rule as u said but the section is not hiding the section.

Comment: Actually i'm getting the dropdown values from an external Data source. Based on one value i have to hide the section

Comment: That should not be the problem. Did you applied rule on that table?

Comment: yes, i have applied the rule

Comment: Also you can review the link which I attached with the answer

Comment: yes, i have followed the link. i applied the rule as like u mentioned

Comment: when i'm adding rule to hide the section, without following the condition the section is hiding